# Finding contour integral of the principal Log

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that $\int_{\Upsilon}\mathrm{Log}z \mathrm{d}z = -2i$
where $\Upsilon(t) = e^{i\pi t}$ for $-\frac{1}{2} \leq z \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

I did:
$$ I = \int_{\Upsilon}\mathrm{Log}z \ \mathrm{d}z \\ = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} i\mathrm{Arg}({e^{i\pi t}}) e^{i \pi t}i \pi \mathrm{d} t\\ = -\pi \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\pi t} \pi t \ \mathrm{d}t$$
since the principal argument of $e^{i\pi t}$ is $\pi t$ due to the domain of $t$.

But this is an odd function so shouldn't it equal zero?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The integrand ${e^{i\pi t}}\pi t$ is niether odd nor even.
But, you can use euler's formula: ${e^{i\pi t}} = \cos \left( {\pi t} \right) + i\sin \left( {\pi t} \right)$

and then employ the fact that $\cos \left( {\pi t} \right) \cdot \pi t$ is an odd function.